# "Use of unresolved identifier" when adding files to an embedded framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, target

I have a framework embedded in an `iOS` app project. It already had some files for some `Swift` classes added to the framework target, they are listed in its "Compile Sources" build phase, and I can use those classes in the rest of the app when importing the framework.

Now I need to add some more files with classes to that same embedded framework. I added them to the framework's target "Compile Sources" like the other files already there, and in the File Inspector for each of those new files I can see their "Target Membership" is correctly set to the framework.

If I build the app, I also see that in the "Products" folder in the Project Navigator that the `MyFramework.framework` is also built, but when I try to use my new classes in the app, the build of the app fails because I get an `Use of unresolved identifier` error message. They are not visible, if I cmd+click on the `import MyFramework` in top of the file where I have it, the public interface that appears only shows me the classes I had already in the framework but not the new ones I added.

I'm trying to look for a solution for this issue with no success, what could I be missing?

Comment: Did you clean your project? also clean build folder?

Comment: Could please add some code where you are getting this error.